# How to join when multiple records are returned which are the same?

Tags: sql, join

i am fairly new to development, so sorry if my question is silly.
I have joined many columns together, and it has a join between a one to many relationships table too.
Anyways the output that i am getting now is

```
Patient_Name    episode_id  DOB     primary_insu        sec_insur   patient_id
name,                    001    03-29-1956  MEDICAID            NULL     12
name,                    001    03-29-1956  NULL         STATEPROB     12
name2                    001    02-20-1981  AETNA             NULL      13
name2                    001    02-20-1981  NULL           MEDICAID      13
```

there is a table which has 2 records for insurance, which is primary insurance and secondary insurance for a patient ID. Is there any way that i can display it in one line for each patient_id.

Current query...

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.LNAME, ''))) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.FNAME, ''))) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.MNAME, ''))) AS Patient_Name,
       pat.episode_id,
       CONVERT (VARCHAR (11), pat.dob, 110) AS DOB,
       CASE 
       WHEN covh.copay_priority = '1' THEN covp.payor_ID ELSE NULL 
       END AS primary_insu,
       CASE 
       WHEN covh.copay_priority = '2' THEN covp.payor_ID 
       END AS sec_insur
FROM   Patient AS pat WITH (NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN
       coverage_history AS covh WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON pat.patient_id = covh.patient_id
          AND pat.episode_id = covh.episode_id
       INNER JOIN
       coverage AS cov WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON cov.patient_id = covh.patient_id
          AND cov.episode_id = covh.episode_id
          AND cov.hosp_status_code = covh.hosp_status_code
          AND cov.coverage_plan_id = covh.coverage_plan_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       coverage_plan AS covp WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON covp.coverage_plan_id = covh.coverage_plan_id
          AND covp.hosp_status_code = covh.hosp_status_code
WHERE  covh.hosp_status_code = 'op'
       AND (covh.effective_to IS NULL
            OR covh.effective_to > GETDATE());
```

Comment: if you provide us with the query we might be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MAX()` to combine the rows:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.LNAME, ''))) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.FNAME, ''))) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.MNAME, ''))) AS Patient_Name,
       pat.episode_id,
       CONVERT (VARCHAR (11), pat.dob, 110) AS DOB,
       MAX(CASE 
       WHEN covh.copay_priority = '1' THEN covp.payor_ID ELSE NULL 
       END) AS primary_insu,
       MAX(CASE 
       WHEN covh.copay_priority = '2' THEN covp.payor_ID 
       END) AS sec_insur
FROM   Patient AS pat WITH (NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN
       coverage_history AS covh WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON pat.patient_id = covh.patient_id
          AND pat.episode_id = covh.episode_id
       INNER JOIN
       coverage AS cov WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON cov.patient_id = covh.patient_id
          AND cov.episode_id = covh.episode_id
          AND cov.hosp_status_code = covh.hosp_status_code
          AND cov.coverage_plan_id = covh.coverage_plan_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       coverage_plan AS covp WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON covp.coverage_plan_id = covh.coverage_plan_id
          AND covp.hosp_status_code = covh.hosp_status_code
WHERE  covh.hosp_status_code = 'op'
       AND (covh.effective_to IS NULL
            OR covh.effective_to > GETDATE())
GROUP BY LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.LNAME, ''))) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.FNAME, ''))) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.MNAME, ''))),
       pat.episode_id,
       CONVERT (VARCHAR (11), pat.dob, 110)
```

Comment: there is no primary insurance and secondary insurance fields, they are found with a column called 'copay_priority' when it is 1, its primary and when it is 2, its secondary

Comment: Well 2 `JOINS` probably makes more sense in that case, but you could still use `MAX()` by wrapping whatever logic you have that results in those two fields in `MAX()`

Comment: Updated to use your query.

Comment: i tried this, well, one more question. there are fields for addresses for the primary and secondary insurances, how can i put that into the query too?

Comment: To avoid using `MAX()` you'd have to `JOIN` twice, to add the address fields you'd just copy the logic `MAX(CASE 
       WHEN covh.copay_priority = '2' THEN covp.payor_ID 
       END) AS sec_insur` and replace the `THEN` with the relevant address field.

Answer (score 0):

You would join to the table twice once to get the primary and once to get the secondary. Use a left join because not all patients will have insureance. Example follows. You will need to adjust it for your actual table strucuture and any other joins you need to get other information.

```
SELECT p.Patient_name,  i1.insurancename AS primary_insure, i2.insuranceName AS secondary_insure
FROM patient P
LEFT JOIN PatientInsurance i1 ON p.patient_id = i1.patient_id AND i1.insurance_type = 'Primary'
LEFT JOIN PatientInsurance i2 ON p.patient_id = i2.patient_id  AND i2.insurance_type = 'Secondary'
```

Comment: when you join twice, the number of tables returned will also be more right? i just want one record to be displayed.

Comment: that is why I added where insurancetype =  to the on clause. You would need to come up with a condition that will make the join one-to-one and that is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: got it.. thank you.. well.. i tried both using the max and 2 joins.. working fine.. thank you so much guys.. i dont know what i would have done without you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can join to the same table twice, using different conditions and aliases for each.

```
   SELECT 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.LNAME,''))) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.FNAME,''))) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.MNAME,''))) AS Patient_Name, 
    pat.episode_id, 
    convert(varchar(11),pat.dob,110) AS DOB, 
    pIns.payor_ID AS Primary, 
    sIns.payor_ID AS Secondary
from 
    Patient pat with (nolock) 
    left join coverage_history pIns with (nolock) on 
        (pat.patient_id=pIns.patient_id)
        and 
        (pat.episode_id=pIns.episode_id)
        and 
        (pIns.copay_priority = '1')
    left join coverage_history sIns with (nolock) on 
        (pat.patient_id=sIns.patient_id)
        and 
        (pat.episode_id=sIns.episode_id)
        and 
        (sIns.copay_priority = '2')
 (remainder of where clause)
```

Comment: its a large code, thats why i didnt copy it, i am editing it and am pasting it

Comment: SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.LNAME,''))) + ', ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.FNAME,'')))+ ', '+ LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(pat.MNAME,''))) AS Patient_Name,
pat.episode_id,
convert(varchar(11),pat.dob,110) AS DOB,
primary_insu=case when covh.copay_priority='1' 
then covp.payor_ID
else null
end,
sec_insur=case when covh.copay_priority='2'
then covp.payor_ID
end
from Patient pat with (nolock)
inner join coverage_history covh with (nolock) on pat.patient_id=covh.patient_id and pat.episode_id=covh.episode_id

Comment: inner join coverage cov with (nolock) on cov.patient_id=covh.patient_id and cov.episode_id=covh.episode_id
and cov.hosp_status_code=covh.hosp_status_code and cov.coverage_plan_id=covh.coverage_plan_id
left join coverage_plan covp with (nolock) on covp.coverage_plan_id=covh.coverage_plan_id and covp.hosp_status_code=covh.hosp_status_code
where covh.hosp_status_code='op' 
and (covh.effective_to is NULL or covh.effective_to>getdate())

Comment: Edited my answer to match your schema.  Obviously can't test, but you should be able to see where it is heading.

Comment: Moved OP's query into the question

Comment: Edited my query to fix the select clause

Comment: but when you join it twice, the number of rows returned will be more, right?

Comment: No, the "xxx.copay_priority = 'y'" part of the join clause limits it to only the primary or secondary record.  Without this, you are correct, it would return more rows